# Правильны ли знаки препинания? (1)

Tags: пунктуация, вставная-конструкция

Предложение такое:

> "И рассудил [Аллах] – Преславен Он! –
>   что [ислам] есть лучшая из религий".

Comment: @Аня Шум-Дождя, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

> Правильные ли знаки препинания?

Такая пунктуация возможна. См. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#pp128 :

> **§ 97...** В тексте вставной конструкции сохраняются все
> необходимые для нее знаки (запятая,
> восклицательный и вопросительный
> знаки, многоточие, двоеточие):
>
> *Давно хочется приобрести специальную посудину с суживающимся верхом **—
> какое-то у нее смешное название? —**
> но всё не попадается.*

**P.S.**

Смущает прописная в написании "**П**реславен"... (Но это к пунктуации не имеет отношения!)

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что предложение должно быть оформлено так:

**И рассудил [Аллах], — преславен Он! — что [ислам] есть лучшая из религий.**

**1.** Наличие при первом тире запятой — в качестве дополнительного знака — связано с условиями контекста. Без восклицательной вставки предложение выглядит так:
*И рассудил [Аллах], что [ислам] есть лучшая из религий.*

Можно привести и другие примеры:

***Называли фамилии мужей и братьев,*** — живы ли, здоровы ли они? — **как будто этот военный мог знать по именам все тысячи рабочих, дравшихся на всех фронтах.**
А. Н. Толстой

*В руке моей — какое чудо! — твоя рука, и на траве два изумруда — два светляка*.
А. Фет
[**Знаки препинания при вставных конструкциях**](http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/znaki-prepinaniya-pri-vstavnyih-70991.html)

**2.** Обычно слово ***преславен*** в сочетании с Аллах, Он, Властелин, Хранитель пишется со строчной буквы:

Отдельно оговорим, что речь Аллаха, **превелик Он и преславен**, не обязательно идет от первого лица...
Хвала Аллаху, Он является источником милостей, **преславен Он**, не счесть славословий Аллаху, и только Аллах оказывает содействие.